# Is there any alternative for auto &c in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I am a beginner and new to this platform. I am trying to run a program to test a valid password with uppercase, lowercase letters and at least one number. Part of the program is...

```
bool hasUpperCase(const string password)
{
    for (auto &c : password)
    {
        if (isupper(c))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have tried compiling the whole program with my compiler which is Falcon C++ but it keeps giving me this error

> 'auto' will change meaning in C++0x; please remove it

How can I remove it and what is its alternative?

The program runs on other compilers such as Onlinegdb.com and C++ shell

Comment: You shouldn't remove it. Your compiler uses an older standard where `auto` had a different meaning. It was removed and later added with it's new meaning. C++0x stands for C++11 (2011). Your compiler uses a standard that is older than 10 years. The next older standard is C++03 (18 years old). You should update your compiler or set a different C++ standard. C++ has strongly changed in the last 18 years.

Comment: If really you are obliged to keep this old compiler, just use: `(char &c ...)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using an outdated (version of your) compiler, this compiler acknowledges breaking changes coming in C++11 which was standardized 10 years(!) ago. Every modern compiler compiles at least with C++11 as base which would remove this error.

The easy and only good solution is to update your compiler, if you for some reason can't do that then change it to `char&` (but actually please just update).